# Symfony 2: how to read excel file content usin PHPExcel

Tags: php, symfony

I am using PHPExcel with Symfony 2 and showing the content of an excel file like this:

```
    $users = array();
    foreach($excel as $i=>$row) {
    if($i !== 1) {          
        array_push($users,array(
            'row'=>$i,
            'name'=>$row['A'],
            'lastname'=>$row['B']
//...and so on

        ));         
    }

}
```

**Question**: 
How can I show the content using the row name instead of $row['A']..ect?
As $row['name']... I mean the name of the excel row.
Example: 
A = name B = email...and so on...
I would like to show the content like this:

```
    $users = array();
    foreach($excel as $i=>$row) {
    if($i !== 1) {          
        array_push($users,array(
            'row'=>$i,
            'name'=>$row['name'],
            'lastname'=>$row['surname']
//...and so on

        ));         
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "row name".. rows are 1-2-3-4-5-6.. columns are A-B-C-D-E.. 
The way you are doing it at the first code is the right one.. else you have to make custom mapping which is just pointless ..

Comment: Hi Svelio, yes I need a custom mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that I answered this question barely a week ago.... assuming that row #1 contains your headers:

```
if($i == 1) {
    $headers = $row;
} else {
    $row = array_combine($headers, $row);
    array_push($users,array(
        'row'=>$i,
        'name'=>$row['name'],
        'lastname'=>$row['surname']
        //...and so on

    ));         
}
```